# SystemExit: 1 Error on using kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have the kivy version 1.10.0 and python version 3.6.1. When I am running the very first example from https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/kivy/latest/kivy.pdf I am getting an error.

Here is my code

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.label import Label


    class MyApp(App):

       def build(self):
           return Label(text='Hello world')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
       MyApp().run()$
```

This is the error that i am getting.

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1

Comment: You're on Windows? Are you sure you did all required [installation](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installation) steps including installing dependencies?

Comment: Windows 10. I hadn't added all the dependencies. After adding I ran the code but it looks like I have to use a higher version of OpenGL (2.0 or higher)

Comment: @Debobrata Rajak, did you find a way to deal with this? Stuck with the same problem currently.

Comment: No. I tried getting a higher openGL 2.0 but I didn't proceed any further. I actually was playing with kivy so I didn't spend much time after that. If you find a solution do upload it here. Sorry for not being of any help!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. I was able to fix it by running the following commands:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
py -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
py -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
```

good luck!

Answer (score -1):

It seems like a dependencies problem. Install these dependencies in the project folder and you will probably be fine (I am assuming that you're using W10).

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.22 kivy_deps.glew==0.1.12
python -m pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.17
```